# GAS - What methods will be useful for taking text from one sheet and moving it to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'll try to keep this as short as possible:

I've got a spreadsheet with one sheet of inventory and one sheet of form responses. I want to create a code that creates a report of sorts based on the form responses. Responses consist of a group name, UID for item requested, and quantity. Groups put in one response per request, so there's multiple responses per group.

I'd like to create a report function that creates a new sheet and fills it in with data. The sheet will be taking group number from the form response sheet, and will be taking the item name, item description and the quantity. This is the simplest solution I've thought of so far, but I can't figure out how I would go about this. Current code is as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Create Report')
      .addItem('Create a new report', 'reportCreator')
      .addToUi();
}

function reportCreator() {
 //creates new sheet and makes it active
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]); 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.showSheet();
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fDnIY_YMC5hNX_FpnWXKmEmaw4pLrQd612ID78hyJRI');
 sheet.copyTo(destination);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
 var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet2.hideSheet();
 var totalSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[totalSheets-1]);

 //adds data to the new sheet

}
```

This creates a copy of a sheet that has a row of headers and formatting already done, leaving space for input below.

Does anyone have any ideas on what methods I might use, or of any existing code that does similar to what I need that I could use for this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With Range.getValues and Range.setValues  you can read and write information in a spread sheet https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()   Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks, I that looks really helpful! I think I can definitely use Class Range, I hadn't actually realize that one existed, and getValues and setValues looks really useful.